# printf type id values in objective c

Tags: objective-c

how to printf type id in objective c. Below is the sample code.

Code :-

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

```
int sizeArr;

scanf("%d", &sizeArr);

int arrayValues;

for(int i=0; i<sizeArr; i++)
{

    scanf("%d",&arrayValues);
    [arr addObject:@(arrayValues)];
}

printf("values entered are :");

for(int i=0; i<sizeArr; i++)
{
    printf("%@", [arr objectAtIndex:i]);  //How to printf array values. 
    // above statement is showing a warning invalid conversion to specifier '@'
}
```

Comment: You could probably do `printf("%s", [[[arr objectAtIndex:i] description] UTF8String]);`.

Comment: this is printing a garbage value from memory :- 543212016-03-01 20:03:36.759

Comment: What input are you putting into your `scanf`s to get that output?

Answer (score -1):

Try

`NSLog(@"value at index %d is %@",i, [arr objectAtIndex:i]);`

Comment: The question asks how to do it using printf

Comment: @circuitry, as for me it doesn't follow from the question.